# Retrieving a list of objects from a linq expression

Tags: c#, linq

I am attempting to retrieve an object[] from a Linq expression. I use the method name and object array in order to create a cache key as a string. In the end, it will enable me to execute a line like this:

```
int id = 123;
DeleteCacheItems(()=> someInstance.GetCachedItem(id, null))
```

The key would resolve to "NameSpaceOfSomeInstance.SomeInstance_123_null"

My unit test works ok:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CacheDeleteViaExpressionTest()
{
    int id = 3186718;
    var something = ProviderFactory.Instance.Get(ProviderType.Something);
    string methodName = CacheMethodManager.GetExpressionMethodFullName(() => something.GetRealtimeRooms(spid, null)); //returns ok
    var objects = CacheMethodManager.GetExpressionArgumentValues(()=> something.GetRealtimeRooms(spid, null)); 
    // returns object[0] = 3186718
    // returns object[1] = null

    string key = MethodCacheKey.GetCacheKey(methodName, objects, something);
    Assert.IsTrue((int)objects[0] == id);
    Assert.IsTrue(objects[1] == null);
}
```

Now I have an MVC controller action that attempts to use this code. I am finding that the object array is only populated with the value types if the expression contains local variables.

If I use **id** from the parameter in the action, it does not work. If use **localId it works**.

I have implemented the mechanism described here ([Getting object array containing the values of parameters from a Lambda Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546850/getting-object-array-containing-the-values-of-parameters-from-a-lambda-expressio)). 
The problem is a bit different in that I have a recursive call to resolve the ConstantExpression.

```
[HttpPost]        
public ActionResult ClearCache(int id)
{
    try
    {
        CacheMethodManager manager = new CacheMethodManager();
        var objects = CacheMethodManager.GetExpressionArgumentValues(()=> something.GetRealtimeRooms(**id**, null));
        //here object[0] = "DisplayClass<> "  // <---------------- This uses a closure class or something that wraps the value

        int localId = id;
        var objects2 = CacheMethodManager.GetExpressionArgumentValues(()=> something.GetRealtimeRooms(localId, null));
        //here object2[0] =  3186718 // <---------------- WORKS

        return Json(new { result = "OK!" });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Json(new { result = "Error", message = $"{e.Message}" });
    }

}

public static object[] GetExpressionArgumentValues(Expression<Action> expr)
{
    var call = (MethodCallExpression)expr.Body;
    var args = call.Arguments;
    object[] methodArguments = args.Select(c =>
      c is ConstantExpression
      ? ((ConstantExpression)c).Value
      : Extension.GetValue(Extension.ResolveMemberExpression(c))).ToArray();

    return methodArguments;
}

public static MemberExpression ResolveMemberExpression(Expression expression)
{

    if (expression is MemberExpression)
    {
        return (MemberExpression)expression;
    }
    else if (expression is ConstantExpression)
    {
        return (MemberExpression)expression;
    }
    else if (expression is UnaryExpression)
    {
        // if casting is involved, Expression is not x => x.FieldName but x => Convert(x.Fieldname)
        return (MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)expression).Operand;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException(expression.ToString());
    }
}

public static object GetValue(MemberExpression exp)
{
    // expression is ConstantExpression or FieldExpression
    if (exp.Expression is ConstantExpression)
    {
        var o = (((ConstantExpression)exp.Expression).Value)
                .GetType()
                .GetField(exp.Member.Name)
                .GetValue(((ConstantExpression)exp.Expression).Value);
        return o;
    }
    else if (exp.Expression is MemberExpression)
    {
        return GetValue((MemberExpression)exp.Expression);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Why does the expression behave differently? How could we  handle this internally so that developers dont need to create local variables?

Thanks
S

Comment: Both snippets should (and does) produce closure and behave identically. Consider providing minimal, but full code which can be copy/pasted and run to reproduce the issue ([mcve]).